# PayPal Pro Hosted Solution Iframe responsive CSS

Tags: paypal

I have integrated PayPal Pro with Magento 2.

I have a problem with PayPal Iframe responsive. After Iframe work layout looks like mess.

[image]

Comment: We don't provide solutions, as long as the problem statement is not clear and precise. Please show at least, how exactly you integrated the iframe and what existing CSS instructions you already have.

Comment: We have set up PayPal Pro with Magento 2 e-commerce application. Magento 2 default provide a configuration where we have to add API username, password and signature, and PayPal email id. It will automatically setup and display Iframe while we placing an order. You can check here it is not showing proper layout on the desktop view. https://i.imgur.com/uKiemlT.png but it is display proper responsive view on the mobile layout https://i.imgur.com/00qNbvg.png